# Editing a Polyline in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using Google Maps V3 API to create a polyline with 2 points. Now that I have created the polyline, I want to shorten it.

**Problem:** I need the polyline to extend from the start point to the midpoint between the start and end points. How can I achieve this?

*The closest function that I can find is `computeDistanceBetween()` function for finding the distance between 2 LatLng points.*

**Javascript Code**

```
    start_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.354183,-71.065063);
    end_latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(42.354183,-71.069063);

    start_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: start_latlng,
        map: map
    });
    end_marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: end_latlng,
        map: map
    });

    path = [];
    path.push(start_latlng);
    path.push(end_latlng);

    var polyline = new google.maps.Polyline ({
        strokeColor: "#970E04", 
        strokeOpacity: 1.0, 
        strokeWeight: 2, 
        path: path,
        map: map
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great resource for mapping functions:

http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

There is an example for calculating a midpoint.